# I'm trying to have excel compare the contents 2 cells on separate sheets and if they match return the contents of a new cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically Sheet A has all the business names and associated phone numbers, Sheet B only has the business names. I can't just copy paste because Sheet A has 2 types of businesses, class A and class B. On sheet B, I only need the phone numbers for the Class A businesses. I need to pull the phone numbers from Sheet A and insert them into Sheet B. The way I need it done is by taking a specific cell in Sheet B that contains the business name and search the entire F column on Sheet A for a match. Then if there is a match, I need to take the contents of a new cell in Sheet A (ex: G1 which holds a phone number) and return the contents to Sheet B (H1).

I've tried IF, VLOOKUP and MATCH and can't get them to work.

Comment: Make it easier on readers by posting a screenshot of your data layout.  This sounds like a pretty basic problem.

Comment: try Index/Match duplet, - should work

Comment: This is a classic; e.g. in `H2` of sheet `B`: `= INDEX(A!G$2:G$10,MATCH(A2,A!F$2:F$10,0))` or `VLOOKUP(A2,A!F$2:G$10,2,FALSE)`. Correct `A2` to the column where the businesses are and adjust the rows. Note that `VLOOKUP` wouldn't be possible if the phone numbers were to the left of the businesses in sheet `A`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Ok, I'm with you on VLOOKUP. I think the issue I'm running into now is that excel isn't recognizing the when I try to select a cell on Sheet A. I'm using VLOOKUP but when I toggle to Sheet A VLOOKUP function doesn't recognize that I've selected A2. It auto fills VLOOKUP('Sheet B'!. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.